# Who do you follow on Google Reader for .NET and Programming/Architecture related stuff?

Tags: feed

I am very interested in not as much as what they write but what they read. Anybody following some good feeds in google reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow [Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/)  and others on his blogroll

- [Ian Griffiths](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/)
- [Chris Anderson](http://www.simplegeek.com/)
- [Jon Jagger](http://www.jaggersoft.com/)
- [But Uncle Bob (ObjectMentor)](http://www.butunclebob.com/)

and people on their blogrolls and people on their blogrolls ....:-). I just travese the tree in Breadth First Order(root=Jon Skeet's Blog).

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman -

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/

Scott Guthrie -

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more all encompassing but you should check out Chris Alcock's Morning Brew each day.  There are always .NET architecture tidbits.
http://blog.cwa.me.uk/tags/morning-brew/\

Answer (score 0):

The De-facto guy is [Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/) (Oren).